# OpenShift "oc rsync" command downloads files, but still outputs WARNING

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

From my Windows machine,

```
oc rsync pod_name:/remote/path/to/dir /local/path/to/dir -c container_name
```

seems to be working and downloading files.. but with:

```
WARNING: rsync command not found in path. Download cwRsync for Windows and add it to your PATH.
```

So, it complains that there is no `rsync`, but there *is* one and it is actually working.

My understanding is, that `oc rsync` looks for `rsync` in the directories available on PATH environment variable. And even if I don't have `rsync` on the PATH, `oc` still runs its *own* `rsync`, as it has the one built-in and it runs its own one, under the hood (correct me if I'm wrong).

Could I get rid of this annoying warning message? can I, somehow, instruct `oc`/`windows` that all is fine?

Any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `-q`, (or `--quiet=true`) to suppress non-error messages.

Comment: I don't want to silence the warning, I want to make OpenShift (or whatever needs to) understand, that there is no problem. By silencing, I will effectively silence all the other possible warnings.. and I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the cwRsync client from this URL and add it to your Windows PATH.

https://itefix.net/cwrsync-client